# How to get mean of exams by client with 2 tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, average

I know a little bit of sql, only the basic, now I need to create a analytic query but can't do this yet.

I have 2 tables on my db oracle, client and exams:

[image]

[image]

I am tried a lot of ways to get the mean of exams by client, but no success yet.4

The result expected is:

exams = 13

clients = 6

13/6= 2.166666666...7

[image]

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have clients who have not taken any exams then you want:

```sql
SELECT AVG(COUNT(e.nu_ordem)) AS avg_exames_by_client
FROM   cliente c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN exames e
       ON (c.id = e.id_cliente)
GROUP BY c.id;
```

or:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM exames) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cliente)
         AS avg_exames_by_client
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE cliente (id PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE exames (nu_ordem PRIMARY KEY, id_cliente) AS
SELECT  1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | AVG_EXAMES_BY_CLIENT |
> | --- |
> | 2.166666666666666667 |

If you then add a couple of clients but no more exams:

```sql
INSERT INTO cliente (id)
SELECT 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8 FROM DUAL
```

Then the average is:

> | AVG_EXAMES_BY_CLIENT |
> | --- |
> | 1.625 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=7a6770ba78a1ef5beb84b696af9e137b)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try below formula to get the result -

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT id_cliente)
  FROM exams;
```

Comment: This is only correct if all the clients have taken at least one exam. If there are clients who do not have a row in the exams table then the average will be incorrect.

Comment: @MT0, But OP never specified that he needed all the clients even if any client have not taken any exam.

Comment: It is implicit from the requirement to "get mean of exams per client" that you would include all of the clients.